How strong is this logical argument (de-extinction)?
Consider the following logical argument:

Extinction, by definition, means "cannot be brought back". Therefore de-extinction is a contradiction in terms.

How strong is this argument, and what are its weaknesses?

Technological changes change what can and cannot be done.

Semantically, it seems a strong argument. Practically, it's nonsense, since de-extinction is the term currently being used whether we like it or not. (I don't.) Language is inconsistent, paradoxes are common, we manage to communicate anyway so it doesn't matter.

'Extinction, by definition, means "cannot be brought back".' Do you have a source for this? The dictionaries I checked have a much weaker definition.

The logic of the argument is strong:

Extinction means "cannot be brought back".
De-extinction means "brought back from extinction".
Which means "brought back from where it cannot be brought back from".

That's a classical contradiction in terms. However the argument is not strong because the first premise is false.

Why is the first premise false?

@CosmicGenis, because that's just not what "extinct" means. Here is the first definition from an online dictionary: "no longer existing or living".

By an astonishing coincidence your perplexing question was posted just as I was participating in a seance conducted by an exceptionally gifted and sensitive medium who had engaged in conversation the spirit of Bertrand Russell. To Russell I took with the following result the opportunity to raise your question. After a moment's contemplation he recalled the occasions upon which he had extinguished his pipe by tamping the glowing baccy with a thumb and knocking the dottle out against the Aberdeen granite of the hearth in his study. The extinction of the pipe, he pointed out, could be readily reversed by relighting it. After I asked the medium if there were any other suitable spirits whom she might call upon to comment, she raised the ghost of Francis Crick, who gave another example, citing the possibility that the extinction of a species might be reversed by clever manipulation of surviving DNA samples. It seems, alas, that your argument is utter tosh, according to those two great gentlemen.

Your premise is simply wrong. The definition of extinct is "no longer in existence".
In the case your premise were correct, which it isn't, one could also appeal to a status quo fallacy, that is, a reliance of the premise to the current status of science.

The argument is unsound.
The conclusion does not follow from the stated premise.
Even assuming the premise were true ("Extinction, by definition, means "cannot be brought back"), that does not logically imply the conclusion (that "de-extinction is a contradiction in terms").
One would require additional premises about the meaning of words prefixed with "de-" or about the meaning of "de-extinction" specifically, and at least one premise about what makes something a "contradiction in terms."
Of course, if you consider a different argument, with the missing premises included, it becomes a sound argument.
